CVXPY DCP error for cp.outer with two decision variables
I'm trying to solve the problem of finding an optimal choice of parallelization algorithm for each operator (v) in a Machine Learning computation graph, where each algorithm has an associated compute cost c_v and communication cost d_v. These vectors have size n which is the number of possible algorithms.
The equation is attached, where s_v is the Boolean (one-hot) choice vector for operator v, and c_v, d_v are the cost vectors. The second term considers the resharding cost between operators – the (n, n) matrix R_vu represents the communication cost between operators v and u when u takes input from v, which depends on the parallelization algorithms chosen for u and v. Since the second term is quadratic, we linearize it by introducing a new variable e_uv which has shape (2n), and flattening the R_vu matrix.
This is a self contained version of the code:
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

n = 10

nodes = [
    {
        "compute_cost_vector": np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
        "all_input_nodes": [],
        "opt_var": None,
    },
    {
        "compute_cost_vector": np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
        "all_input_nodes": [0],
        "opt_var": None,
    },
]

expr = 0
const = []

for node in nodes:
    opt_var = cp.Variable(n, boolean=True)
    node["opt_var"] = opt_var

    const += [cp.sum(opt_var) == 1]

    expr += opt_var.T @ node["compute_cost_vector"]

    for in_node_idx in node["all_input_nodes"]:
        in_node = nodes[in_node_idx]
        in_opt_var = in_node["opt_var"]

        resharding_cost = np.random.randint(
            1, 10, size=(opt_var.shape + in_opt_var.shape)
        )
        flattened_resharding_cost = np.matrix.flatten(resharding_cost)

        e_var = cp.Variable(opt_var.shape + in_opt_var.shape, boolean=True)
        expr += cp.vec(e_var).T @ flattened_resharding_cost

        const += [cp.sum(e_var) == 1, e_var == cp.outer(opt_var, in_opt_var)]

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(expr), const)
prob.solve()

This is the error that occurs:
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The following constraints are not DCP:
var16 == reshape(var8, (10, 1), F) @ reshape(var1, (1, 10), F) , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  reshape(var8, (10, 1), F) @ reshape(var1, (1, 10), F)

When I run this, cvxpy doesn’t like the constraint on e_var, saying that the cp.outer(opt_var, in_opt_var) operation doesn’t follow DCP rules. However, as far as I know, the function f(x, y) = xy^T is convex when x, y are bounded to be non-negative. Do you know what might be going on, and if there is a way to solve this problem using cvxpy?
I expected cvxpy to recognize that the outer product operation is convex when the vectors are non negative, however I'm getting DCP errors.

I could not attach the image, but here is the equation in latex form:
\begin{equation}
\underset{s}{\min} \underset{v \in \mathcal{V}}{\sum} s_v^T (c_v + d_v) + \underset{(v, u) \in \mathcal{E}}{\sum} s_v^T R_{vu} s_u
\end{equation}

I think this is not convex. Note that all nonlinear equality constraints are non-convex, and also note that for scalars x,y the product x*y is non-convex.
